Pigeonhole Principle Question: Place 1600 points inside a unit square such that there is at least one point inside every rectangle of area 1/200

Tim wants to place $1600$ points inside a unit square such that there is at least one point inside every rectangle of area $\frac{1}{200}$ and with sides parallel to those of the
square. Is it possible to do it? If your answer is yes, please give an example and show that it works. If your answer is no, please prove it is impossible.

A rectangle of area $\frac{1}{200}$ may be $\frac{1}{10} \times \frac{1}{20}$ or $\frac{1}{200} \times \frac{1}{1}$ or $\frac{1}{1} \times \frac{1}{200}$, ... .
In my research, to make sure that every rectangle of area $\frac{1}{1} \times\frac{1}{200}$ or $\frac{1}{200} \times \frac{1}{1}$ contains at least one point, we need to make sure that in every row and column of the grid of $200 \times 200$ must contains at least one point. This strategy needs $200 \times 200=40,000$ points.
I would appreciate any help, especially a hint or approach that I can use to find the rest of the solution on my own!

I think the key idea might be the fact, that $1600 = 40 \times 40$ so we can try to create grid such that each side of initial square is divided into $40$ parts

I think I have solved the problem in the way I mentioned. Think about some assignment of points that is symmetric to X and Y axis and is realted to number $5$ (since $200 / 40 = 5$, this is just some intuition). If you don't mind I will post my solution later

@RupertRybka Please share your solution

Let's assume $(0,0), (0,1),(1,0),$ and $(1,1)$ are the corners of the unit square.
Place $200$ points on the coordinates $(\frac{i}{200}, \frac{1}{2})$, where $0 \leq i \leq 199$. Then, every rectangular with sides $x$ (horizontal side) and $y$ (vertical side) such that $\frac{1}{200} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{100}$, and hence $\frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{1}$, contains a point (why?).
Next, place $200$ points on the coordinates $(\frac{2i}{200}, \frac{1}{4})$ and $(\frac{2i}{200}, \frac{3}{4})$, where $0 \leq i \leq 99$. Then, every rectangular with sides $x$ (horizontal side) and $y$ (vertical side) such that $\frac{1}{100} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{50}$, and hence $\frac{1}{4} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}$, contains at least a point (why?).
Next, place $200$ points on the coordinates $(\frac{4i}{200}, \frac{1}{8})$, $(\frac{4i}{200}, \frac{3}{8})$, $(\frac{4i}{200}, \frac{5}{8})$, $(\frac{4i}{200}, \frac{7}{8})$, where $0 \leq i \leq 49$. Then, every rectangular with sides $x$ (horizontal side) and $y$ (vertical side) such that $\frac{1}{50} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{25}$, and hence $\frac{1}{8} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{4}$, contains at least a point (why?).
Finally, place $200$ points on the coordinates $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{1}{16})$, $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{3}{16})$, $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{5}{16})$, $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{7}{16})$, $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{9}{16})$, $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{11}{16})$, $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{13}{16})$, $(\frac{8i}{200}, \frac{15}{16})$, where $0 \leq i \leq 24$. Then, every rectangular with sides $x$ (horizontal side) and $y$ (vertical side) such that $\frac{1}{25} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{10 \sqrt 2}$, and hence $\frac{1}{10\sqrt 2} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{8}$, contains at least a point because every rectangular with sides $x$ (horizontal side) and $y$ (vertical side) with $\frac{1}{25} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{10 \sqrt 2}$ intersects a line that is divided into $16$ equal segments and $\frac{1}{16} \leq \frac{1}{10 \sqrt 2}$. Note that the same reasoning applies to all the "why?"s above.
So far, we have placed $200 \times 4$ points. By the same argument and adding $800$ more points in a completely similar way but in the $90^{\circ}$-rotated coordinate system (or simply where the axes are swapped), we can prove the same about every rectangular with sides $x$ (vertical side) and $y$ (horizontal side) such that $\frac{1}{200} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{10\sqrt 2}$. Moreover, note that the smaller side of any rectangular of area $\frac{1}{200}$ must be less than or equal to $\frac{1}{10\sqrt 2}.$
We are done.

First of all to avoid working with fractions let's scale the problem such that our $1 \times 1$ square becomes  $200 \times 200 $. Now we will be considering rectangles with area equal to $200$.
First of all let's divide the big square into squares of size $5 \times 5$ (each side is divided into $40$ equal parts so in total we have $1600$ such squares). Then we have to draw lines as shown in the picture:

We must repeat that structure among whole square and place our points in places where green lines cross with each other within $5 \times 5$ squares. Let's now notice some facts:

Green lines are perpendicular (this falls immedietely if we consider their slopes which are $\frac{1}{5}$ and $-5$).
They cross inside of some $1 \times 1$ square (this is beacuse if you consider one of them you can see that it does not cross any dashed line before it reaches next $5 \times 5$ square, so it must cross with the other somewhere in between).
If they cross at some point with coordinates $(x_0, y_0)$ then they also cross at points $(x_0 + 25, y_0)$, $(x_0, y_0 + 25)$, $(x_0 -25, y_0)$, ... (this is beacuase we just repeat that pattern which has size of $25 \times 25$).
They cross exactly once in every single $5 \times 5$ square so we have in total exactly $1600$ such points.

Now let's prove that this in fact satisfies given conditions. By symmetry of that structure I can assume that if considered rectangle has size $A \times B$ where $A$ is the horizontal size, then $A \leqslant B$. Since $A \cdot B = 200$ we must have $A \geqslant 1$. Let's split the problem into two cases:
Case 1: $A \leqslant 7$
Since $A \leqslant 7$ we can deduce that $B \geqslant \frac{200}{7} > 28$. Now consider the "horizontal distance" (difference of $x$ coordinates) of the consequtive crossings.

We want to find $|CD|$. We know $\frac{|CD|}{|AD|} = \frac{1}{5}$ so by simmilarity $\frac{|BC|}{|AC|} = \frac{1}{5}$ but $|AB| = 5$ ($|AB|$ is parallel to side of square and with green lines it forms the parallelogram). By Pythagorem theorem we can now easilly get $|BC| = \frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}$, but now $|CD| < |BC| < 1 \leqslant \text{size of shorter side of rectangle}$.
So the rectangle must lie on some veritcal line that contains $x$ coordinate of one of our points. Now since we know that the larger side of the rectangle has lenght at least $28$ which is greater than $25$ we know that it must contain at least one of our points, beacuse they are placed in the distance $25$ from the other at the same $x$ coordinate.
Notice that even if we consider the point that is just next to the edge of the big square the reasosing still works, since it lies in some $1 \times 1$ square so its distance from edge is less than $1$.
Case 2: $A > 7$
From $A \cdot B = 200$ and $A \leqslant B$ we can deduce that $A \leqslant 10\sqrt{2} \leqslant B$. Since both $A$ and $B$ are greater than $7$ then this rectangle must fully contain some $6 \times 6$ square from our grid. But by invesitgating the image below it is obvious that it must contain some black square (which is the square in which some green lines cross).

If you prefer more algebraic argument then notice, that those black squares are translated by $5$ in consequtive columns and distance between two of them in one column is $24$ white squares. Now distance of the closest black square in first column of our $6 \times 6$ square can be at most $24$ but then in the next columns the black squares will be closer and closer and in the end they will appear in our square since the total translation will be equal to $5 \cdot 5 = 25$ and side of our square is $6$ which is larger than $5$ so they won't "jump over" it.
Thus it must contain some of our points.

Thanks, I learnt a lot from your solution
